# Can i use 'console.log' in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i try to make some chrome extension, i need debug.

i want use chrome dev tool, console.

[image]

I write console.log in code, devtool is just clear.

like this.

```
function doExportToDisk() {
    console.log("es on. ");
}
```

i search on google, i found this.

```
function doExportToDisk() {
  var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
  bkg.console.log('foo');
}
```

but is dosen't work, too.
now i use aleat. but it's too Inconvenience.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: "console.log('loads');
}, callbackFindIDsFromPage);
```

this is work. but it's so Limited.
i want use powerful log. help!

Comment: Can you not use the dropdown where it says `top` and find your extension there, it seems like that would show you the console logs then

Comment: @George  i can find it. but i select, change anything.
you mean change 'top' to extenstion name, right?

Comment: The popup is a separate window, which has a separate devtools - right-click the popup and click "Inspect". More info: [Google Chrome / Firefox do not see extension output in console](//stackoverflow.com/a/38920982)

Comment: It's been a while since I created a chrome extension.  You could add a div to the page and put your logs in that.  If you make it position absolute and give it a high z-index, that will work.

Comment: @ wOxxOm  OMG... i never thought that! you save me! thanks!!! can you teach me how to select answer your comment?